# Pandas: Write dataframe containing strings to xlsx with multiline format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsx

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['abc\n123\n232','1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6'])
df.to_csv('text.csv')
```

I would like to have in a single cell in the xlsx (Edited: not csv):

```
abc
123
232
```

The desired output is A1 cell **only** being filled.

The dataframe has only 1 cell.
But the above code would result in the xlsx (Edited: not csv) printing that 1 cell into multiple cells.
Is there a way to format and write the xlsx (Edited: not csv) into **multilines** *within* ***each* cell**?

Edit:
I shall clarify my problem. There is nothing wrong with my dataframe definition. I would like the "\n" within the strings in each cell of the dataframe to become a line break within the xlsx (Edited: not csv) cell. this is another example.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['abc\n123\n232','1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6'])
df.to_csv('text.csv')
```

The desired output is A1 and A2 cells **only** being filled.

Edit 2:
Not in csv but **xlsx**.

Comment: I don't understand your question. CSV files do not have "cells" - would you like to explicitly store `\n` within strings? In that case, you can just escape your escape character, e.g. `\\n`.

Comment: @jpp I guess that was the problem. I mistook CSV for excel document. But the desired results is still the same. \n to indicate line breaks within the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) with `index=False` and `header=False`.

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

But you may need to turn on 'Wrap Text' by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

why not use openpyxl for that it will work

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
worksheet.title = "Sheet1"
worksheet.cell('A1').style.alignment.wrap_text = True
worksheet.cell('A1').value = "abc\n123\n232"
worksheet.cell('B1').value = "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6"
workbook.save('test.xlsx')
```